# Under what circumstances would the OS be aware of threads created by Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, kernel, cpython, gil

My understanding is that in general the OS Kernel (e.g. Linux) does **not** really have visibility into any threads created in user space. Moreover, I believe in Linux specifically the OS kernel only sees "tasks" or processes, and not "threads" per se.

Additionally, I'm not sure if CPython would actually ever use multiple threads for anything unless one uses explicitly e.g. the `threading` package in Python **or** one of the C standard Python libraries chooses to create threads itself. I suppose the exception here is `multiprocessing` or any Python libraries that may also spawn multiple processes, in which case the OS Kernel sees them as separate.

Under what set of of circumstances would the OS Kernel be aware of any threads created by a Python script, including any of the modules it may use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux:

*task* is a *thread*, *process* is an address space with one or more threads.

User-space threads are directly represented in the kernel. There is POSIX API to create threads `pthread_create` and there is Linux implementation of threading APIs called NPTL which maps one user-level thread to kernel-level task (`task_struct`).

`CPython` `multithreading` module implements threads using `pthread_create`.

Comment: I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434103/4531): _"In practice, programs wishing to keep track of their own threads would rely on APIs provided by the threading library they’re using, instead of using OS-specific information. Typically on Unix-like systems that means using pthreads."_ Since this Q concerns CPython, I'd assume you are effectively implying it uses `pthreads`?

Comment: @Josh I am not going to read and comments on someone's webpage, sorry, despite it being low quality.

Comment: Thanks. Leaving `multithreading` as well as any  non-standard packages aside for a moment, does the CPython interpreter ever use multiple kernel threads during the lifetime of a program to execute it and interpret Python bytecode?

Comment: @Josh If you look into [`task_struct`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched.h#L632), you should spot the 1st member is `thread_info` - the thread the `task_struct` represents.

Comment: @Josh Some detailed info: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ps2SH727eCIC&lpg=PA689&ots=kMKcz7BVw5&pg=PA686#v=onepage&q&f=false